# SAS to PySpark Conversion

Tags: pyspark, sas

I have the following SAS code:

```
   data part1;
       set current.part;
       by DEVICE_ID part_flag_d
       if first.DEVICE_ID or first.part_flag_d;
           ITEM_NO = 0;
       end;
       else do;
           ITEM_NO + 1;
       end;
   run;
```

I am converting this to PySpark and getting stuck. I have the 'part' DataFrame. Where I am getting stuck is trying to convert the following line:

```
   if first.DEVICE_ID or first.part_flag_d;
```

I know it's getting the first entry of each column, but is it also checking for null? What is the OR condition saying?

Would appreciate any direction on how to script that line.

Comment: For simplicity, you can always concatenate the two columns and use `if first.concated_col` for `OR` cases. That said, there are surely plenty of other ways of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the documentation for the `by` statement:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/a000202968.htm#a002651313

> ## Processing BY Groups
>
> SAS assigns the following values to
>   FIRST.variable and LAST.variable:
>
> FIRST.variable has a value of 1 under the following conditions:
>
> when the current observation is the first observation that is read
>   from the data set.
>
> when you do not use the GROUPFORMAT option and the internal value of
>   the variable in the current observation differs from the internal
>   value in the previous observation.
>
> If you use the GROUPFORMAT option, FIRST.variable has a value of 1
>   when the formatted value of the variable in the current observation
>   differs from the formatted value in the previous observation.
>
> FIRST.variable has a value of 1 for any preceding variable in the BY
>   statement.
>
> In all other cases, FIRST.variable has a value of 0.
>
> LAST.variable has a value of 1 under the following conditions:
>
> - when the current observation is the last observation that is read from
>     the data set.
> - when you use the GROUPFORMAT option and the internal value of the
>     variable in the current observation differs from the internal value in
>     the next observation.
>
> If you use the GROUPFORMAT option, LAST.variable has a value of 1 when
>   the formatted value of the variable in the current observation differs
>   from the formatted value in the next observation.
>
> LAST.variable has a value of 1 for any preceding variable in the BY
>   statement.
>
> In all other cases, LAST.variable has a value of 0.

Answer (score -1):

Please see the code below. It is generated by an automated conversion tool called SPROCKET you can find the info about it [here](https://www.wisewithdata.com/sas-to-pyspark-migration-solution-2/)

It should take care of the `first.variable`

```
# DATASTEP
part1 = (
    CURRENT_part_df # change to your set df name
    .withColumn('_first_DEVICE_ID', when(
        row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(['part_flag_d']).orderBy('DEVICE_ID')) == 1, 1)
        .otherwise(lit(0)))
    # WARNING: NO ORDER DETECTED, MANUALLY SPECIFY ORDER VARIABLE
    .withColumn('_first_part_flag_d', when(
        row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(['DEVICE_ID','part_flag_d']).orderBy("")) == 1, 1)
        .otherwise(lit(0)))
    .withColumn('ITEM_NO', expr("""case
        when (_first_DEVICE_ID > 0 or _first_part_flag_d > 0) then 0
        when not ((_first_DEVICE_ID > 0 or _first_part_flag_d > 0)) then ITEM_NO + 1
        else ITEM_NO end"""))
    .drop('_first_DEVICE_ID')
    .drop('_first_part_flag_d')
)
```